# Missing System.Drawing .NET 4.5 VS 2k12

Tags: asp.net, .net, system.drawing

I have a web project in Visual Studio 2012, with 4.5 as target framework. Now I wanted to use System.Drawing, the reference is there (by default, I did not add it) but it has a yellow icon next to it. When building this is my errormessage:

1>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3267: The primary reference "System.Drawing", which is a framework assembly, could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "System.Drawing" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Drawing".
1>  DrawingTest -> D:\Project\DrawingTest\DrawingTest\bin\DrawingTest.dll

It looks like it is looking for a 4.0 assembly?

how can I resolve this?

(I tried remove/add reference)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190885/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-drawing-or-one-of-its-dependencies-erro) post. I think it's the same problem that you're experiencing.