# Executable generated with TFS throws an exception on launch

Tags: c#, .net, exception, tfs, .net-assembly

I am seeing different behaviors when I try to launch an application compiled by Visual Studio versus it being compiled by TFS.
When I launch the executable generated by Visual Studio it works fine but it's not the case when I'm using the .exe generated with TFS. My application crashes at loading and according to CLR Debugger

Une exception non gérée du type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' s'est produite dans mscorlib.dll

Error message in french :

> Informations supplémentaires : Impossible de charger le fichier ou
>   l'assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ou une de ses dépendances. La
>   définition trouvée du manifeste de l'assembly ne correspond pas à la
>   référence de l'assembly. (Exception de HRESULT : 0x80131040)

It's talking about Version 4.0 of the assembly but I'm using the Framework 2.0.

Does someone know what the cause of this problem might be?

Comment: Looks like you missing a reference. When you say TFS, do you mean, continuous integration?

Comment: Yes it looks like it but I don't understand why I don't have problem compiling with Visual Studio. Yes I'm using TFS as source controller and I try to automate my builds with TFS build definitions.

IBuildDefinition buildDef = BuildServer.GetBuildDefinition("MyApp", "Definition");
            IQueuedBuild queuedBuild = BuildServer.QueueBuild(buildDef);

Comment: It must comes down to `msbuild`. TFS tells it to use wrong framework. Look into your build properties

Comment: I've added the argument "/p:TargetFramework=2.0" to MSBuild but it still not working

Comment: A similar issue was resolved here but I'm not using VS2010 but 2005, and my .resx file is already correct :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190885/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-drawing-or-one-of-its-dependencies-erro