# .NET 3.5 looking for .NET 4.0 dll after deployment

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, .net-3.5

I have a project that I build on a Win 7 machine with Visual Studio 2012 or 2013 (same results with each). It has always targeted .net 3.5. After installing some Windows updates last week, I now get this error on some machines (that haven't installed the same updates, it works fine on my machine) when trying to start it from its deployment package.

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

If I open it in dotpeek I can see that the references are asking for .net 4.0 files. I've combed through past SO posts that mention a VS bug and lingering references to

```
System.Drawing, Version=4.0...
```

but a find all on my solution shows that all System.Drawing references are correctly asking for 2.0.0.0.

I've repaired all the .NET installations on the build machine, but nothing is solving the problem. As far as I know I have multi-targeting packs installed correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: Try one of the solutions from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190885/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-drawing-or-one-of-its-dependencies-erro

Comment: Have you tried using ILDASM to look at the manifest node and see what version of each assembly is referenced?

Comment: @JakobOlsen I have tried all of those with no success.

Comment: @YvesRochon In dotpeek I see system.drawing 4.0 in the references, however I have triple checked in VS as well as removed and readded the 2.0 version of system.drawing. If I try to open it with ILDASM v3.5, the program crashes.

Comment: Ok... Then try to increase the build output verbosity.  
Go to Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run and increase the build output verbosity to 'diagnostic'    
This will give you a very detailed build output. Search this output for System.Drawing, and you may be able to see what is referencing the wrong version.

Comment: I'm on VS2013 btw. It may work differently if you are on VS2012.

Comment: @JakobOlsen All the resolutions for the dll look like this: ResolvedFrom={TargetFrameworkDirectory}
 18>                  Version=2.0.0.0
 18>          C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Drawing.dll

Comment: System.Drawing can also be referenced by your .resx files.  Sometimes hard to see when the resource was serialized as a base64 string.  That's a possible explanation for why it bombs, not for how they got messed up.

Comment: @HansPassant I can understand that. The reason it is confusing for me is that between the builds that worked and the ones that don't work anymore, no resx files have been changed that reference System.Drawing according to our git history, and none appear to change during the build. The only resx files with changes are the ones containing localized strings. It seems like an environment problem because of the fact that some Windows updates seemed to set it off, but I have no idea where to begin looking. System restore to a date prior to the updates didn't resolve the problem either.

Comment: Don't assume anything when you got a weird problem.  Actually look at the files, Notepad will do fine.

Comment: @HansPassant Following the stack trace leads me to System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String name, CultureInfo culture, Boolean wrapUnmanagedMemStream) inside the InitializeComponent method of a user control. The resx file for this control hasn't been modified for 2 years, so I guess I don't understand how it can be failing all of a sudden. Anyway, thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I love a psychic debugging session that turns out to be 100% accurate.