# How do I install System.Drawing.Common in a project that uses '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, installation

I am trying to write some unit tests in C# in a '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2' application but all tests give the next error:

> 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file
> specified.'

When I try to install `System.Drawing.Common` I get the next error from the NuGet package:

Could not install package 'System.Drawing.Common 4.5.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets
'.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more
information, contact the package author.

I cannot change the application version or the framework (.NET Core 2.1) and any other trick I found online did not work (or generated more errors).

Help?

Comment: Are you using 4.5.x or Core 2.x ?  I am confused.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190885/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-drawing-or-one-of-its-dependencies-erro

Comment: Correct me if I'm worng, but it looks to me that you are trying to add the nuget package System.Drawing.Common to a .net 4.5 application. In .net 4.5 system.drawing is an integrated part and you just add it as a reference under Assemblies (Reference Manager)

Comment: I have a solution with multiple projects. The project I work with has the target framework Core 2.x. The error mentions .net 4.5.2.

Comment: I'm trying to add the reference to the package Drawing.Common. I have a dll in my computer but the application does not take it, so I tried to install it again and got the other errors

Answer (score 13):

in NuGet put this line:

```
Install-Package System.Drawing.Common -Version 4.5.2
```

in .NET CLI put:

```
dotnet add package System.Drawing.Common --version 4.5.2
```

in Paket CLI put:

```
paket add System.Drawing.Common --version 4.5.2
```

Comment: That's where I got the second error. I did not even find System.Drawing in the Manage nuget ... for solution

Comment: Add :  System.Drawing.Bitmap
System.Drawing.BitmapData
System.Drawing.Brush
System.Drawing.Font
System.Drawing.Graphics
System.Drawing.Icon

Answer (score 4):

I have cloned solution https://github.com/barnhill/barcodelib . It has two projects: library project targets .Net Standard 2.0 and refers to System.Drawings.Common. Example project depends on library and has reference to System.Drawings.Common. Example project was not compiling due to same error.

My solution was just to remove reference to System.Drawings.Common in NuGet packages and read it (rclick on Example project > Manage NuGet packages > Browse Installed, remove the System.Drawings.Common package, and then add it back), unload project and then reload it again

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of bizarre but it worked dramatically so I'm going to mention it.  I built a small vs 2017 ent console project that was supposed to read an oracle database.   When I started to run it I got the System.Drawing.Common error mentioned above.  It seemed stupid because I wasn't really doing anything having to do with Drawing at all.    In Manage Nuget Packages I deleted the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess driver and added the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core and the System.Drawing.Common error went away and I was able to read my oracle database.  So I'm suggesting that with NuGet you may be picking up some things you really don't need and if you have any choice for your NuGet packages, try different ones.   This also may be some foible with how my organization managed nuget for Visual Studio 2017 enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

> I managed to solve it by restarting Visual Studio, changing the framework to 4.6.1 (which I could not do before) and adding the reference.

<sub>OP's solution migrated from the question to an answer.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use one of the libs described in here instead https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-image-processing/

you could try to use https://www.nuget.org/packages/CoreCompat.System.Drawing/ as well and maybe try to change your app framework to .net standard 2.0?

Comment: I tried installing it directly and adding it to the project, but it won't see my dll. I use System.Drawing for one line only(I need to get the dataset from a report design to compare) and I cannot modify the entire solution for my test project

Comment: You said that you wanted to write some unit tests, last time I saw an issue when someone was not able to add reference to MS Test project so he had to rebuild whole solution and turn off and on again whole Visual Studio... But I rather guess that your problem is related with your framework version. Do you try to add reference through nuget to all your solution or only your .net core 2.1 project? You could try to update .net framework version to compatible to .net standard 2.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/standard/net-standard