# Openfiledialog throwing System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, multithreading, file, openfiledialog, system.io.file

I was implementing openfiledialog and after I run the program I get this error

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing.Common,`

I don't know why it happens, I tried removing multi-threading but still, it didn't work I also tried adding STAThread but it didn't work as well, it's expected to open up a new window but it doesn't
here's the code

```cs
Thread thread = new Thread(delegate () 
{
    Console.Title = $"Low Pixel | Loading Combos...";
    
    using (OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        dialog.Title = "Load Combo List";
        dialog.Filter = "Text Files |*.txt";
        dialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
        // sets the settings of the dialog

        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Checker.Combo = new ConcurrentQueue<string>(File.ReadAllLines(dialog.FileName));
            // sets the combo variable to read the filename of the dialog selected file
            Console.WriteLineFormatted("Sucessfully loaded {0} lines of combos", Color.Aqua, Color.LightBlue, new object[]
                    {
                        Checker.Combo.Count()
                    });
            Thread.Sleep(2500);
            
            return;
            // returns to the method that the function has been called from
        }
    }
});

thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

thread.Start();
thread.Join();
```

Comment: Call `File.ReadLines` rather than `File.ReadAllLines`. Only call the latter if you specifically need an array containing all the lines. You don't. That constructor takes an `IEnumerable<string>` and copies the data anyway, so `ReadLines` is more efficient.

Comment: Why are you displaying a dialogue box on a secondary thread? It might make sense to read the selected file on a secondary thread but you would do that after the dialogue has been displayed on the UI thread and a selection made. DO NOT do UI stuff on any thread other than the UI thread. Displaying a dialogue box is obviously UI stuff.

Comment: There is no hint that this code actually needs System.Drawing.  You're not just debugging your own code anymore when you use OpenFileDialog, you also get to see any mishap reported by shell extensions that are installed on the machine.  If one of them was programmed in a .NET language (bad idea) and fails with an exception then you'll get a notification for it.  Just the notification, the dialog otherwise will seem to work just fine.  SysInternals' Autoruns is useful to disable troublesome extensions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install System.Drawing.Common in a project that uses '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54984173/how-do-i-install-system-drawing-common-in-a-project-that-uses-netframework-ver)

Comment: I agree that this is all suspect: You haven't set `STAThread` and you don't have a message loop, because it's a background thread. Not your issue now, but can cause other problems

Answer (score -1):

Check your nuget packages, the error seems like you're missing System.Drawing.Common which I believe is needed to render the dialog