# Could not load type 'System.Drawing.BitmapSuffixInSatelliteAssemblyAttribute' from assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-10, .net-4.0

When trying to build and run a multiproject solution in Visual Studio 2019 Professional, it gives me the error:

> Unknown build error, 'Could not load type
> 'System.Drawing.BitmapSuffixInSatelliteAssemblyAttribute' from
> assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral...

It is isolated to one specific project called `TheConfig` and if I delete that project, the rest builds without issue, however I do need that project for some work.

I am currently unsure how to proceed. I've tried all the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190885/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-drawing-or-one-of-its-dependencies-erro) with no success thus far. Throughout my testing, the error has always remained the same.

One last thing, multiple coworkers of mine have checked out the same project, built and ran it with no changes to their IDE or environment. We're all new hires and have roughly the same setup (Windows 10, Fresh install of Visual Studio 2019 Pro, .NET desktop development workload installed, application targets .NET Framework 4)

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I installed Nuget package [`System.Drawing.Common`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/) to test, and everything works fine. Try to update the package version to `5.0.2`.

Comment: @KyleWang I'm sorry I don't quite understand. What did you want me to update? I thought my packages (through the VS installer) were already up to date. If you mean the drawing package itself, the option seems to be greyed out.

Comment: What I mean is that confirm you are using `System.Drawing.Common 5.0.2`. If this not help you, try to submit an issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues).